# Needless Argument in Ruby optparser

Tags: ruby, command-line-interface, optparse

I am facing issue with following code for parsing command line options

```
#!/usr/bin/env ruby
require 'optparse'

options = {:username=>nil}
optparse = OptionParser.new do|opts|
    # Define the options, and what they d
    opts.on( "--username", "Cassandra username" ) do |username|
        options[:username] = username
    end

    opts.on( '--password', 'Cassandra password' ) do |password|
        options[:password] = password
    end

    opts.on( '--keyspace', 'Cassandra keyspace' ) do |keyspace|
        options[:keyspace] = keyspace
    end
end
puts ARGV

optparse.parse!(ARGV)

puts options
```

When I run this code from commandline as

```
./testopt.rb --username=uuuuu --password=xxxxxx --keyspace=test
```

I get following output

```
--username=uuuuu
--password=xxxxxx
--keyspace=test
./testopt.rb:25:in `<main>': needless argument: --username=uuuuu (OptionParser::NeedlessArgument)
```

What am missing?
I am in `ruby 2.2.3p173 (2015-08-18 revision 51636) [x86_64-linux]`

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 6):

Although [@mudasobwas answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47668711/1680728) is not wrong in itself, you can have `"option=value"` parsing by specifying the option like in the example below (mmh, **tested with ruby 2.3.1 only**).

Key is to use `opts.on('--username=USER',...` vs. `opts.on('--username',...` .

```
#!/usr/bin/env ruby
require 'optparse'

options = {:username=>nil}
optparse = OptionParser.new do|opts|
    # Define the options, and what they do
    opts.on( "--username=USER", 'Cassandra username' ) do |username|
        options[:username] = username
    end

    opts.on( '--password=PASSWORD', 'Cassandra password' ) do |password|
        options[:password] = password
    end

    opts.on( '--keyspace=KEY', 'Cassandra keyspace' ) do |keyspace|
        options[:keyspace] = keyspace
    end
end
puts ARGV

optparse.parse!(ARGV)

puts options
```

You do not loose the ability to pass the value without the equal-sign using this approach and have it converted to string:

```
➜  ~  /tmp/op.rb --username myuser           
--username
myuser
{:username=>"myuser"}
➜  ~  /tmp/op.rb --username=myuser
--username=myuser
{:username=>"myuser"}
```

Comment: Thanks @Felix ! This explains well.

Answer (score 0):

Remove equal signs. `OptParser` expects spaces between arg names and args:

```
./testopt.rb --username uuuuu --password xxxxxx --keyspace test
```

Comment: But now everything has become true. Any quick hint? {:username=>true, :password=>true, :keyspace=>true}

Comment: Put the type explicitly as a second parameter of a call to `opts.on`. What is the issue to [read the documentation](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib/libdoc/optparse/rdoc/OptionParser.html)?

Comment: The options I am putting out are showing as--- {:username=>true, :password=>true, :keyspace=>true}

Comment: @AmitTeli: yes, because you don't specify the type. Have you read the link mudasobwa provided?

Comment: Yes I am going through the link. I was lost in so many unrelated links, And the example I referred was not using type. Thanks @SergioTulentsev

Comment: Don’t refer “examples,” refer the documentation.

Comment: @mudasobwa First time I downvote you I think! :) You can have the OP desired behaviour, see my answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/47669963/1680728 .

Comment: @Felix I know it’s possible. The thing is it contradicts the unix-desired behavior, make shell completion harder to implement and in general is a code smell.

Comment: @mudasobwa I see most core utils working this way (accepting both "=" and space). About shell completion I cannot say anything, but as it is already implemented this sounds like a 'should not have happened' argument.

Comment: @Felix oh, indeed; Thanks. I have no idea why I had this erroneous impression, my bad. Thanks again!